# Rake fails installing apriori.rb gem on windows

Tags: ruby, installation, rake

Pretty straight forward:

```
C:\Ruby192>gem install apriori
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing apriori:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        "C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe" -rubygems C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=C:/Rub
y192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/apriori-0.2.2/lib RUBYLIBDIR=C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/apriori-0.2.2/lib
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- config/requirements

(See full trace by running task with --trace)


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/apriori-0.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/apriori-0.2.2/./gem_make.out
```

I'm new to ruby and gems, but if I got it right the one complaining is the RakeFile:

```
require 'config/requirements'
require 'config/hoe' # setup Hoe + all gem configuration
```

But the file is really there:

```
c:\Ruby192>ls -l C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/apriori-0.2.2/config
total 2
-rw-r--r--    1 fgadotti Administ     2877 Oct 31 14:59 hoe.rb
-rw-r--r--    1 fgadotti Administ      655 Oct 31 14:59 requirements.rb
```

Could it be a problem with windows paths? For some reason preventing rake from finding the files?